# Ajax return html page insted of json wordpress

Tags: html, json, ajax, wordpress

I having issues with the response of my php script, the php script have to return a json but instead of that it is returning all the page html. I have change the datatype value in the js to see what was the response but if i put json instead it give me an error status 200 readystate 4 OK.

PHP File

```
    function enque_invitados(){
        wp_register_script('lp-lista-invitados', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/lista-invitados.js', array('jquery') ); 
        wp_enqueue_script('lp-lista-invitados');
        wp_localize_script('lp-lista-invitados','ajax_dcms_invitado',array('ayaxurl'=>admin_url('admin-ajax.php')));    

        add_action('wp_ajax_ajax_invitar','ajax_invitar');      
        add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_ajax_invitar','ajax_invitar');           

    }
}

if (is_user_logged_in()) {
    add_action('init', 'enque_invitados');

}

function ajax_invitar(){
     echo json_encode('test');
     die();  

}
```

JS File

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

$('form#invitar').on('submit', function(e){
    //do stuff


    object = {'action': 'ajax_invitar', //calls wp_ajax_nopriv_dcms_invitado
            'first_name':    $('form#invitar #Fname').val(), 
            'last_name':     $('form#invitar #Lname').val(), 
            'cedula':        $('form#invitar #ci').val(), 
            'options':       $('input[name="options"]').val(),   
            'options1':      $('input[name="options1"]').val(),
            'menu':          $('form#invitar #menu_invitados').val(),    
            'acompaniantes': $('form#invitar #acompaniantes').val() };
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        url: ajax_dcms_invitado.ajaxurl,
        data: JSON.stringify(object),
        dataType: 'text',
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
        },error: function( error ){
            console.log("Error");
            console.log(error);
    }
    });
     e.preventDefault();    
});
```

});

Comment: Have you looked at https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_(action) ?

Comment: yes, i have looked it but even using its example code i get the same response